# Cannot set controller to authenticate using client_credentials flow with devise doorkeeper

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

I have a rails application with devise, doorkeeper and [devise-doorkeeper](https://github.com/betterup/devise-doorkeeper).

Most of it use devise auth, but I want to provide an api for other application, using the [Client credential flow for doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Client-Credentials-flow).

I configured doorkeeper to take client_credientials flow, and successfully managed to get a token. However, when querying this controller :

```
class InvestmentsController < ActionController::API
  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!

  def show
    business = BusinessObject.find_by(code: params[:code])

    render json: business.to_json, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Sending a query to this methods properly fail with improper token (401), but with a proper valid token, I still have a 404, my code retrieve business and put it to json, but then during the render, I have the error :

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=>

Note that if I manually sign-in a user, I won't have any error. I could create specific users for client_credentials applications but that defeat the purpose of client_credentials which is supposed to use oauth_applications (with id and secrets) and not users...

Comment: This appears to be an issue with devise-doorkeeper.

https://github.com/betterup/devise-doorkeeper/issues/13

Comment: @Dargor is this worked for you ? I am in the same situation but it is not working for me.